# How to hide Twitter Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is getting annoying — when I click on an item in a Bootstrap dropdown, the dropdown doesn't close. I have it set up to open a Facebox lightbox when you click the dropdown item but there is a problem with it.

[image]

---

### *What I have tried*

When the item is clicked, I tried doing this:

```
    $('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
```

That hides it, but then for some reason it won't open again.

As you can see I really need the dropdown to close, because it looks crappy when it stays open (mainly because the `z-index` of the dropdown is higher than the Facebox modal box overlay.

---

### *Why I'm not using Bootstrap's built-in modal box*

If you're wondering why I'm not using the nice-looking modal box *built into Bootstrap*, it is because:

1. It doesn't have a way to load content into it with AJAX.
2. You have to type HTML each time for the modal; with Facebox you can do a simple: `$.facebox({ajax:'/assets/ajax/dialogs/dialog?type=block-user&id=1234567'});`
3. It uses CSS3 animations to animate (which looks very nice) but in non-CSS3 browsers it just shows, which doesn't look that nice; Facebox uses JavaScript to fade in so it works in all browsers.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
```

This may also work for you:

```
$('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');
```

Comment: I updated the code. Give it a try again please. I tried this on opened dropdowns and it closed them fine. I could also reopen them afterwards.

Comment: It still didn't work. This is my code: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25819920/Screenshots/Screen%20shot%202012-06-08%20at%208.38.31%20PM.png `#block_user` is the item in the dropdown. I also even tried *without* the comma in the selector as your code is but neither work.

Comment: I added another method that may work for you. If it doesn't, double check that the div.btn-group element that holds your button has the class "open" assigned to it.

Comment: `.dropdown('toggle')` closes the dropdown but also disables it from opening again! I don't know what is the use of that!

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me: $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');

Comment: @orad It did that for me too (hence my comment "Hmm it didn't work"). If you haven't already, try the second one.

Comment: In some mobile devices the dropdown is closed but the overlay of the last selected menu is still shown.

Comment: when I use .dropdown('toggle'), other click handlers attached to items within the dropdown stop working. I don't have this problem when I use the .parent().removeClass('open') method, however.

Comment: `dropdown('toggle')` is [documented here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage)

Comment: I don't like `toggle` especially on `mouseleave`. Just inspect your DOM for whatever element that has the `open` class added to it and this should be the one you should remove the `open` class from. This answer helped; thanks =)

Comment: Heads up: removing the `open` class works, but it doesn't update `aria-expanded`. Always better to use the API when possible.

Comment: @claviska so how to use the API properly in this case? Do you mean using `dropdown('toggle')`? But this could actually open the dropdown as well, right?

Comment: `$('.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');` will work on standalone dropdown buttons, to make it also work for dropups and button groups you can do `$('.open>.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');`

Answer (score 27):

tryed out most the options from here but none of them realy worked for me. (the `$('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');` did hide it, but if you moused over before clicking  anything else it showed up again.

so i endet up doing it whith a `$("body").trigger("click")`

Comment: That's a good way of doing it too! So when you virtually click on the `<body>`, it closes the drop down?

Comment: yeah the dropdown is listning on click events from the user outside of the menu. :)

Comment: @VeXii yes, and that's the reason of it not closing itself on mobile devices. Hope the new bootstrap version 3 ("mobile first") fixes this.

Comment: Works without a flaw.

Answer (score 12):

```
$('.open').removeClass('open');
```

Bootstrap 4 (October 2018):

```
$('.show').removeClass('show');
```

Comment: I think this is really the simplest solution, except with Bootstrap 4 you use the class 'show'.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done without writing JavaScript code by adding attribute **data-toggle="dropdown"** into anchor tag as shown below:

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Another action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The simpliest and most relevant answer for me. Well explained. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You only need to do `$('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');` remove second line which hides the dropdown menu.

Comment: But this will not change the aria-attribute.

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me:

```
$(this).closest(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this!

```
.removeClass("open").trigger("hide.bs.dropdown").trigger("hidden.bs.dropdown");
```

OR

```
$(clicked_element).trigger("click");
```

It always work for me.

Comment: U the king! the best thing for me! Tnx!

Answer (score 4):

The selected answer didn't work for me, but I'm thinking it's because of the newer version of Bootstrap.  I ended up writing this:

```
$('.btn-navbar').addClass('collapsed');
$('.nav-collapse').removeClass('in').css('height', '0');
```

Hopefully that's helpful to someone else in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe I am still on Bootstrap 2.2.

Answer (score 3):

Why use my method, because if the user gets out of the div, this metod allows the user a certain delay before the submenus dissapear. It's just like using the superfish plugin.

1) First download hover intent javascript

[Link here : Hover intent javascript](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

2)Here is my code to execute

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var config = {    
            over: showBootrapSubmenu,   
            timeout: 500,
            out: hideBootrapSubmenu  
        };

        function showBootrapSubmenu(){  
             $(this).addClass('open');
        }
        function hideBootrapSubmenu(){  
          $(this).removeClass('open');
            }

        //Hover intent for Submenus
        $(".dropdown").hoverIntent(config);

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation and using JavaScript it could be done using the toggle method:

```
$('.button-class').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-class').dropdown('toggle');
}
```

You can read about it in: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-methods

Answer (score 2):

It may have been added in retrospect (though, that feature is *not* [documented](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#methods), even in Bootstrap 4.3.1), but you can simply call it with a `hide` parameter. Just make sure to call it on the toggler element. Like so:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('hide');
// or
$('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').dropdown('hide');
```

Of course, this also works in reverse with `show`.

Comment: It's referred to obliquely in the [next section](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events) as "the hide instance method".

Answer (score 1):

Try to open HTML with Bootstrap Modal, I use this code:

```
$(function() {
     $('a[data-toggle=modal]').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var page = $(e.target).attr('href');
          var url = page.replace('#','');
          $(page).on('show', function () {
              $.ajax({
              url: "/path_to/"+url+".php/html/...",
              cache: false,
              success: function(obj){
                   $(page).css('z-index', '1999');
                   $(page).html(obj);
              }
              });
         })
     });
});
```

and the link is like this:

```
<a href="#my_page" data-toggle="modal">PAGE</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution on how to close the button dropdown and toggle the button :

```
$(".btn-group.open", this)
    .trigger("click")
    .children("a.dropdown-toggle")
    .trigger("blur")
```

Where "this" is a global container of the button group.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4.1:

```
$(".dropdown-link").closest(".dropdown-menu").removeClass('show');
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting by attribute is the slow way. Here is the fastest solution to hide the opened dropdown:

```
$(".dropdown-menu.show").parent().dropdown("toggle");
```

or use following, if the .dropdown-menu is not the next children element (find the closest parent dropdown control):

```
$(".dropdown-menu.show").closest(".dropdown").dropdown("toggle");
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, i had a navbar and several pulldown menus.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.dropdown-toggle').each(function(){
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            $('li.dropdown').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('open');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is: you add a hide label:

```
<label class="hide_dropdown" display='hide'></label>
```

then everytime you want to hide dropdown, you call:

```
$(".hide_dropdown").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help anyone (maybe it is too specific to my case, and not to this question) but for me this worked:

```
$('.input-group.open').removeClass('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

After click:

```
// Hide mobile menu
$('.in,.open').removeClass('in open');
// Hide dropdown
$('.dropdown-menu').css('display','none');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('display','');
},100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class="dropdown-toggle" on the anchor tag, then when you click on the anchor tag it will close the bootstrap dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this simple jQuery trick should help.

```
$(".dropdown li a").click(function(){
$(".dropdown").removeClass("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easist way:

```
  $('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(){
    $('.navbar-toggle').trigger('click')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in your current event handler

```
$('.in,.open').removeClass('in open');
```

in my scenario I used when ajax call complete

```
jQuery(document).on('click', ".woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons .wc-forward.checkout", function() {
    var _this = jQuery(this);
    ajax_call(_this.attr("data-ajax-href"), "checkout-detail");
    $('.in,.open').removeClass('in open');
    return false;
});
```