# Hide dropdown when modal is showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small problem with my modal window and for some reason I can't figure this out. 
On mobile, I have a hamburger menu and in that menu I have a Log In link which open a modal window. 
Everything works and the modal is showing but the problem is: the dropdown menu is showing on top of my modal.

I tried to hide it using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var modal = $('.modal'); //get modal window

  if(modal.hasClass("in")){ //check if it has class "in"
    $('.navbar-toggleable-md').hide(); //true, hide navbar
  }

}); // end ready
```

What am I missing? Because the code from above it's not doing anything..

Comment: can you post a complete fiddle of your code?

Comment: You should hide it inside the click handler of your menu. Your code will only check once for the class

Comment: $('.navbar-toggle').trigger('click')

Comment: seems `z-index` problem. Increase `z-index` of modal so that it is greater than `z-index` of menu.

Comment: please provide us with fiddle of your code.

Comment: Please check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941540/how-to-hide-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch an event either `show.bs.modal` or `shown.bs.modal` on `.modal`. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('.navbar-toggleable-md').hide();
});
});
```

Read bootstrap docs: [modals-events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

Comment: Its may be problem z-index

Comment: The problem was indeed with the z-index but that's not what I wanted to achieve here. Because even if I set the z-index the menu will be just behind and it will still show on table for example. But, he was right about the event catching. This solved the problem. Thanks! I'll read a bit more about those.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a problem with z-index on our model. increase the z-index of your modal.
OR please provide us with fiddle of your code.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `z-index` of your modal greater than the `z-index` of the dropdown.
In example:

```
.modal {
    z-index: 999;
}
.dropdown {
    z-index: 99;
}
```