# How to close Bootstrap dropdown after stopPropagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

For a specific reason, I had to invoke `event.stopPropagation` within a dropdown member.

Now, the dropdown doesn't close when I click it. How do I force it to close programatically?

My html:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu1<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" id="it1">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="it2">Item 2</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="it3">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#it4-modal">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
```

And my jQuery js:

```
$('#it3').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  doStuff();
});
```

I already tried things like `$('.dropdown-toggle').toggle()` and `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');`, but without success.

Comment: $('.dropdown-menu').toggle(); works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it with

```
$('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');
```

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10941616/6474503

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 (October 2018):

```js
$('.dropdown.show,.dropdown-menu.show').removeClass('show');
```

It hides all opened Bootstrap dropdowns.