# Preventing twitter-bootstrap-3 dropdown from permanently closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

If the `#action` dropdown element is clicked, a confirm dialog is presented, and if cancelled, the dropdown is closed using `.dropdown('toggle')`.

Not as desired, however, the dropdown cannot be reopened without reloading the page.

What is the proper way to close an opened twitter-bootstrap-3 dropdown?

EDIT.  I found I can replace `$("#action").dropdown('toggle');` with `$("#action").removeClass('open');`, however, this does not seem like the "right" way to do it.

```
$("#netstart").click(function(){
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'netstart',
            success: function (rsp){
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert.log(xhr.error);
            }
        });
        location.reload();
    }
    else {
        $("#action").dropdown('toggle');
    }
});


<div class="masthead">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li class='first active'><a href='/settings'>Configuration Settings</a></li>
            <li id='default'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Default Settings</a></li>
            <li id='testRemote'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Test Server</a></li>
            <li><a href='/logs'>System Logs</a></li>
            <li><a href='/backup'>Backup Database</a></li>
            <li id='action' class='dropdown'>
                <a href='javascript:void(0)' data-toggle='dropdown' class='dropdown-toggle'>Action <b class='caret'></b></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li id='reboot'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Reboot</a></li>
                    <li id='halt'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Shutdown</a></li>
                    <li id='netstart'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Restart Network</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li id='logoff' class='last'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Logoff</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: According to your code, confirm dialog is not presented after #action click but #netstart click.. Could you explain what is the purpose of this code and how it should work?

Comment: @bigless  User  clicks `#action`, dropdown opens, user clicks an dropdown option, confirmation dialog is displayed, user either clicks ok and post is made or clicks cancel and dropdown closes.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941540/how-to-hide-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown). Behaviour that you described is also mentioned there so removing class seems to be "right" way cos programatically triggered click is ugly..